# Meaning of 半分間違っているんじゃないかなと思う部分があるから、アメリカチック,アメリカナイズされすぎているっていうか。

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

This is from a textbook, the person is trying to explain how his generation is different from his father's generation. He says that all his father did was work and save money.

> 自分が楽しむとか、遊ぶために稼ぐとかいう感覚じゃなくて、なんか、ただ稼ぐみたいな感覚で稼いでたんじゃないかなと父を見る時に、ちょっと思って。

Then he says:

> 半分間違っているんじゃないかなと思う部分があるから、 アメリカチック,アメリカナイズされすぎているっていうか。

From what I can gather, he is saying that (just working and saving money) is half wrong, and their working ethics (I suppose?) became too americanised.

Am I correct? What does it mean?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Japanese.SE! Could you edit your title (and maybe even your question) to be more specific about what part of the sentence you're not understanding? More specific titles will get the right users to your question and more specific questions help those users better answer your question ;)

Comment: Hi. That phrase is really contextual. Its not clear for native speakers, too.

Comment: More context needed in the actual Japanese words used, not in summarized and translated English.

Comment: Thanks for the context.  This sentence (one starting with 半分), however, is still extremely ambiguous.  I, a native Japanese-speaker, could not tell for sure who is being called "too Americanized" or even "half-wrong".  It is not common for many Japanese to consider working hard  to be an American thing.  If this is important, even more context will be needed to decifer it.  (I am personally more than surprised to hear this was in a textbook.)

Comment: I think the idea of earning money, not for the purpose of having fun or enjoying it, was what he was referring to as being 'half wrong'.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost correct. And I want to mention some details that you didn't mention.

The first sentence means "When I observe my father, I somewhat think he feels like he simply earns money, rather than earning money to have fun or enjoy himself."

The first sentence doesn't mention saving money but earning money without any purpose to spend (e.g. to have fun).

You are correct about the second sentence, but I want to mention one thing to avoid confusion. The second sentence is talking about the father's work ethic being half-wrong, not having a work ethic in common.